# Como calculo a percentagem de o número de respostas certas?

Tags: java, for

Boas, penso que já consegui realizar o que pretendia obrigado a todos a minha única duvida é se é gerado um novo número sempre que o utilizador insere um novo palpite,aqui está o novo código:

```
System . out . println("Indique um valor minimo");
        int min = scanner.nextInt();
        System . out . println("Indique um valor máximo");
        int max = scanner.nextInt();
        System . out . println("Vão agora ser gerados números entre " + min + " e " + max);
        double rand = Math.random();
        int entreMinEMax =(int) (min +(max - min + 1) * rand);
        int palpites = 0;
        int acertou = 0;
        int errou = 0;

        do
        {
            System . out . println("Indique o seu palpite:");
            int palpite = scanner.nextInt ();
            if (palpite == entreMinEMax)
            {
                acertou++;
            }else
            {
              errou++;  
            }
            palpites++;
        }while(palpites<10);

        System . out . println ("Acertou " + acertou + "     "   +  (acertou/10)*100 + "%");
        System . out . println ("Errou " + errou + "     "   +  (errou/10)*100 + "%");
```

Comment: Mas no código se o utilizador acertar à primeira, apenas uma pergunta é feita devido ao `break`, logo nunca será possível ter um caso em que acertou 2 como indicado na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para o teste de sucesso que está a fazer, apenas uma tentativa correta será contabilizada devido ao `break` que tem no `for`. Isto faz com que o cálculo tenha de ser feito apenas considerando as tentativas falhadas previamente.

Pode efetuar o calculo da seguinte forma:

```
sucesso = (total_tentativas - tentativas_falhadas) / total_tentativas
```

Exemplo no código:

```
for(int resposta=0; resposta < 10; resposta++)
{
    System . out . println("Indique o seu palpite:");
    int palpite = scanner.nextInt ();

    if(palpite == entreMinEMax)
    {
        double sucesso = (10.0 - resposta) / 10; //calculo de sucesso
        System.out.println("Parabéns!!Acertou!!");
        System.out.println("Percentagem de sucesso: " + (sucesso*100) + "%");
        break;
    }
}
```

No calculo é feito `10.0 - resposta` pois a variável `resposta` indica a quantidade de tentativas falhadas previamente, pois cada vez que é feita uma nova iteração é porque o utilizador falhou.

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/4OepCE)

Comment: Ok. Fiz agora um update ao codigo e penso que o meu objetivo esteja cumprido mas a minha unica duvida é se é gerado um novo número sempre que o utilizador insira um novo palpite. Aqui esta o novo codigo:

Comment: @Phil Como assim ? Cada novo "palpite" é uma nova tentativa de acertar no mesmo número.

Comment: Mas eu penso que o que o professor pede é que seja gerado um novo numero dentro do intervalo sempre que é dado um novo palpite. Talvez com outro laço do while ou for??

Comment: @Phil Aconselho a ter a certeza do enunciado antes de tentar qualquer resolução, caso contrário não estará a fazer progressos. A alteração que fez à pergunta já invalida de certa forma a minha resposta, e aparentemente ainda vai fazer mais uma. Se tiver a certeza de qual o objetivo estarei disposto a ajustar a minha resposta em conformidade.

Comment: Eu deixo aqui o enunciado só para ter a certeza,pois após ter relido várias vezes ainda tenho duvidas nos objetivos(Português não é muito o meu forte,melhor em inglês):
"Escreva um programa que pede um valor mínimo e um valor máximo ao utilizador. Depois,
o programa entra num ciclo que repete 10 vezes. Em cada interação desse ciclo, o
programa gera um número aleatório e dá 5 tentativas para o jogador adivinhar o número.
De cada vez o programa indica se o utilizador acertou ou não. No final, mostra quantas
vezes o utilizador acertou e quantas errou."

Comment: @Phil Esse enunciado parece contradizer-se. "repete 10 vezes" (...) "e dá 5 tentativas". São 10 vezes ou 5? De qualquer maneira é como está na pergunta